# Is it possible use YamlSlurper and YamlBuilder to find duplicate property names?

Tags: groovy, yaml

If I have a yaml file like this:

```
obj:
  - name: 'msg'
    patterns:
      '("ssn":")([^"]*)(")' : '$1xxxxxxxxx$3'
      '("cvv":")([^"]*)(")' : '$1xxxx$3'
      '("ssn":")([^"]*)(")' : '$1xxxxxxxxx$3'
```

If I use the Groovy YamlSlurper class to load this, the "patterns" object will have two properties, with the following names:

- ("ssn":")([^"]*)(")
- ("cvv":")([^"]*)(")

The third property in the input has a name identical to the first property name, so the third one will override the first (or vice versa).

Is there any way I could use some combination of YamlSlurper and perhaps YamlBuilder to somehow detect that the input has a duplicate property name?

I can see that changing the expected syntax of this file so that it expects a format like this:

```
obj:
  - name: 'msg'
    patterns:
      - '("ssn":")([^"]*)(")' : '$1xxxxxxxxx$3'
      - '("cvv":")([^"]*)(")' : '$1xxxx$3'
      - '("ssn":")([^"]*)(")' : '$1xxxxxxxxx$3'
```

Would give me the ability to detect duplicates.  If I can't detect duplicate property names on the input using the original format, I will consider changing the spec to require the modified format.

Answer (score 0):

behind `groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper` there is a `jackson` library.

[YamlSlurper.parse()](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/3d42f91a996db56630cd27264ce753da3287a718/subprojects/groovy-yaml/src/main/java/groovy/yaml/YamlSlurper.java#L61)
-> [YamlConverter.convertYamlToJson()](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/3d42f91a996db56630cd27264ce753da3287a718/subprojects/groovy-yaml/src/main/java/org/apache/groovy/yaml/util/YamlConverter.java#L41) -> `jackson`

so, you could use it to detect first duplicate:

```python
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature

String yaml = '''
obj:
  - name: 'msg'
    patterns:
      '("ssn":")([^"]*)(")' : '$1xxxxxxxxx$3'
      '("cvv":")([^"]*)(")' : '$1xxxx$3'
      '("ssn":")([^"]*)(")' : '$1xxxxxxxxx$3'
'''

def result =
    new ObjectMapper()
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY)
        .readTree(new YAMLFactory().createParser(yaml))
```

this code throws exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: 
  Duplicate field '("ssn":")([^"]*)(")' for `ObjectNode`: 
  not allowed when `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY` enabled
  at [Source: (StringReader); line: 7, column: 31]
```